# Add alert upon form submission in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, alert

I am having the hardest time trying to get an alert to pop up after clicking on a button. I have been working on it for quite a while but can't seem to figure out where I am wrong. As per the code below, everything works fine, but the Alert will not show up. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdbreact';
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import{ init } from 'emailjs-com';




 function Contact() {
     
    const [alertVisibility , setAlertVisibility ] = useState(false)

  function sendEmail(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    emailjs.sendForm('hidden', 'hidden', e.target, 'hidden')
      .then((result) => {
        setAlertVisibility(true);
        if (setAlertVisibility === true ) {
        
    return(
            
              <button class="closebtn"> 
              Great, your message has been sent.</button>
    )
            } 
    });
  
      e.target.reset();
  };
  

  return (
   
     <div>
       
        <NavBar />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <MDBContainer>
          <MDBRow className = "formcontainer">
            <MDBCol md="6">
              <form onSubmit={sendEmail}>
                <p className="h4 text-center mb-4">Fill in the information below to contact me!</p>
                <br />
                <label htmlFor="defaultFormContactNameEx" className="grey-text" > Your name </label>
                <input required type="text" id="defaultFormContactNameEx" className="form-control" name="user_name" />
                <br />


                <label htmlFor="defaultFormContactEmailEx" className="grey-text"> Your email </label>
                <input required type="email" id="defaultFormContactEmailEx" className="form-control" name="user_email"/>
                <br />


                <label htmlFor="defaultFormContactSubjectEx" className="grey-text"> Subject</label>
                <input required type="text" id="defaultFormContactSubjectEx" className="form-control" name="user_subject" />
                <br />


                <label htmlFor="defaultFormContactMessageEx" className="grey-text"> Your message </label>
                <textarea required type="text" id="defaultFormContactMessageEx" className="form-control" rows="7" name="message"/>
                <div className="text-center mt-4">
                          <MDBBtn color="warning" outline type="submit">
                            Send
                            <MDBIcon far icon="paper-plane" className="ml-2" />
                          </MDBBtn>
                        </div>
                      </form>
                    </MDBCol>
                  </MDBRow>
                </MDBContainer>
                <br />
                <br />
                <Footer />
                </div>
              );
            };



export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating alertVisibility with the useState function, so your check should be for
if (alertVisibility === true) {...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it still didn't work when changing it to alertVisibility instead of setAlertVisibility.... any other suggestions?

Comment: You would most likely need useEffect here

Comment: Thanks all, I ended up getting it to work with useState

Answer (score 0):

You can  use
[SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/recipe-gallery/sweetalert2-react.html)

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { MDBContainer, MDBRow, MDBCol, MDBBtn, MDBIcon } from 'mdbreact';
import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import{ init } from 'emailjs-com';

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';


function Contact() {
const form = useRef();
const sendEmail = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();   

emailjs
  .sendForm(
    EMAILJS_SERVICE_ID,
    EMAILJS_TEMPLATE_ID,
    form.current,        
    EMAILJS_PUBLIC_KEY
  )
  .then(
    (result) => {
      Swal.fire({
        icon:"success",
        title:`<h5 style='color:green'>Message Sent Successfully</h5>`,
        confirmButtonColor: 'green',            
      })
    },
    (error) => {
      Swal.fire({
        icon:"error",
        title:`<h5 style='color:red'>Ooops, something went wrong</h5>`,
        confirmButtonColor: 'red',
        
      })
    }
  );
  e.target.reset()
};
return(
<div>
</div>
)
}
export default Contact;
```